# Data not being entered into sql database

Tags: php, sql, database

I have followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xb8aad4MRx8&t=225s on creating a login system and signup form on a website. I created it on my localhost and it worked perfectly. I have since tried to upload it to my website I have created a database on my server and changed the php code however no data is being entered into the database. My hosting service is 1and1 and below is the code for the code to link the database in php. Password has been changed

```
<?php
$host_name = 'db706265806.db.1and1.com';
$database = 'db706265806';
$user_name = 'dbo706265806';
$password = 'PASSWORD';
$conn = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
```

And this is the code for the signup form

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
include_once 'dbh-inc.php';

$first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first']);
$last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

//error handers
//check for empty fields
if (empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($email) || empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=empty");
        exit();

} else{
    //check if input char are valid
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $last)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=invalid");
        exit();
    }
    else {
        //check if email is valid
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=email");
            exit();
        } else{
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=usernametaken");
                exit();
            } else{
                //hashing the password
                $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                //insert the user into db
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_first, user_last, user_email, user_uid, user_pwd) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email', '$uid', '$hashedPwd');";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}


} else{
    header("Location: ../signup.php");
    exit();
}
```

Any help for why the data isnt being entered would be appreciated

Comment: Do you get any errors? Are you sure, your database settings are correct?

Comment: I dont get any errors and my validating seems to work and gives me the success message in the url however when i then try to login with those details it comes up with the error for the no matching users in the url and there is no data in the database in 1and1s control panel

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. It is STRONGLY RECOMMENDED to use PDO instead.

Comment: I still have this question that are you sure about the values in these variables: `$host_name`, `$database`, `$user_name` and `$password`? Are they correct?

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi, using `mysqli` is also OK if he uses `prepared statement` and `parameter binding`

Comment: Check `$result` for an error. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: OP - I HIGHLY recommend you remove that link if it is a live link. Otherwise some clever use here can destroy your database schema with injection as you have exposed both the backend code and frontend design.